# Thermal printer android out of paper bulkTransfer android not responding

Tags: android, printing, usb, thermal-printer

I'm working on an Android application which communicate with a thermal printer in order to print some receipts.

Here is my code where I send data to the printer in order to print the receipt:

```kotlin
                connection.claimInterface(usbInterface, forceClaim)

                val thread = Thread {
                    connection.bulkTransfer(
                        mEndPoint,
                        printer.toByteArray(),
                        printer.size(),
                        0
                    )
                    connection.close()
                }
                thread.run()
```

This code is working fine if there is paper inside the thermal printer but if there is no paper in the thermal printer, it's just freezing my application and I have to restart the device completely. I know that the timeOut 0 in bulkTransfer method is defined as unlimited according to the doc so I guess that's the reason I got ANR.

I tried to put a timeout of 4000 but the problem is that if the receipt take more than 4seconds to be printed, it just stops the print action after those 4 seconds.

Any idea about how I can handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

That's a common situation for thermal receipt printers.

If there is no paper, the cover(print head?) Is open, or printing is not possible due to some error, there is no communication or just the data is stored in the printer buffer, it will not work.

Perhaps something similar is happening during the bulk transfer.

---

Then, paper feed occurs physically according to the amount of data to be printed, and if you are using it with a paper cutter, it will take time to operate. They are not fixed times.

---

Depending on the features your printer supports, you may or may not be able to do it.

If the printer supports RS232C hardware flow control emulation, the flow control signal line is turned off in the event of an error, so you can determine if printing is possible by checking the status of the signal line before printing.

Then, if you can communicate even in an error state and support a command to notify the printer status(called a real-time command), send that command before printing to receive data indicating the printer status. By examining it, you can determine whether it is possible to print in the same way as above.

[DLE EOT](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=118)

> Transmit real-time status

If such pre-checking is possible, you will be able to find the problem faster than doing a timeout check.

Comment: You mean I have to create byteArrayOf(0x10, 0x04) and pass this array of bytes in the bulkTransfer method, then wait for a response of the printer, and definer if I can launch another bulkTransfer with the data I want to to print ? That's right ?

Comment: First, please check the specifications to see if your printer supports the command. Basically, the command is 3 bytes (0x10, 0x04, 0x01) instead of 2 bytes. The response will tell you the online / offline status. If you want to know more about why the printer is offline, change the third byte, send the command, and judge by the response.